# Synchronised execution of a function using php using windows platform

Tags: php, multithreading, synchronization, scheduling, shopping-cart

The situation here is i am fetching the max value from table and adding it by 1 and setting it as order no for user in my php file but the problem is when two or more users access the same file at once they wl be assigned the same order no so that only one transaction is successful and others failed since i have set order field as unique,i need a help fixing this since i dont have idea on scheduling the function user by user.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of asking the max value in a table, insert a new row for the order. This should also increase the max value. Since two inserts can never be done at the same time, you've solved your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but the scenario is on load of php file i have to get the max value of orderno col from table and i have to pass it to payment api otherwise i could have done as you said by giving autoincrement. On load of file only i have to get the order no.

Comment: Try to be more flexible in your thinking. Clearly you have to store an order number, that is being used, somehow, otherwise it can be used twice.

Comment: But the order no field here is unique i can not use it twice. I want to load the checkout file once when other user accesses it is done.

Comment: Any PHP file or function can be accessed by multiple users at the same time. This is normal, and you should not try to change that. Unique order numbers can be achieved by using the database. There are never two processes accessing the same database table at the same time, it is always done sequentially.

Comment: Ok thank you then what should be the approach for this according to your point of view. Should i generate a random number and append to max order value or is there any other way

Comment: Sorry, I cannot give decent advice based on no code whatsoever. Beside that, you ignore whatever I say. I already told you my point of view: Use the database, it's your central resource and it can contain your unique order numbers.